# How to clean expired tokens from database?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, typescript, express

I'm building a password recovery. When the user requests my application creates a new row with userID, a hash, and expiration date.

Then the user receives an email with the URL containing the hash on the DB. When the URL hash and DB hash matches he can change the password.

What is the best method to delete an expired passwordRecover row?
I thought of 3 possibilities but all of them doesn't seem right.

1. When the password recovery is requested a job is scheduled to delete the row from the database when it expires. (this implies using Redis/Bull to handle the job)
2. Create a trigger on the Database to delete all expired rows when a new row is inserted.
3. Same as 3 but the trigger is in the application instead.

My concern in just leaving the rows in the database and not cleaning it up is to pollute with useless data.

Comment: This is very opinionated so not sure whether there will be a "best" option - it depends on what framework you are using and how much effort you want to spend on this - personally I think all these 3 are OK.

One small suggestion though based on your description - beside sending the hash, you might also want to send the expiration along and an HMAC digest on both the hash and expiration so that you can validate it before you go to db for validation. Just adding a little bit more security to avoid hacker hammering your db with fake hash since this has to be an anonymous api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maintenance tasks like deleting expired data are generally low-priority and their design should err on the side of simplicity.  For this kind of task, it's not really important when exactly it happens, so I'd simply set up a once-a-day cron job that deletes the expired data (eg `DELETE FROM resets WHERE expiration < NOW()`).

Critically, the app's password reset code must compare the expiration date stored in the DB with the current time, and not just rely on the presence or lack of a matching reset token.

Scheduling individual jobs or triggers introduces complexity and/or performance implications that aren't really necessary.

- By not being meticulous about deleting rows exactly when they expire, you avoid the performance penalty of frequently querying for and deleting expired rows.
- Because the app validates a token and its expiration date before resetting a password, the cleanup task becomes mostly irrelevant to the security of the app: if the cron job fails to run for some reason, it doesn't really matter — the app refuses to use the expired token, and the expired data will be deleted next time the cleanup task runs.
- The cleanup task becomes idempontent, so it's safe to run manually ad-hoc or multiple times.